# Why "farcical" rather than "farcic" or "farcal"

Tags: etymology

It seems to me that "farcical" includes 2 suffixes, each for the purpose of making an adjective of a noun. I presume this would normally be considered redundant and wrong, but has become dictionary-correct because of common usage.

Do I have that right, or is there some other reason for the word "farcical" being constructed the way that it is?

Comment: It's not the only such word. Symmetrical, cyclical, ...

Comment: It may be "redundant" but that does not mean it is "wrong".

Comment: Please include the research you’ve done.

Comment: @Randal'Thor: There are also examples of the opposite happening, e.g. electrical => why electric**ity** instead of electric**y**, or then use the adjective electric**ital**? (note: I'm applying OP's principle, I'm not advocating that we should change the word)

Comment: @Flater - electrical is from electric, https://www.etymonline.com/word/electric - and dates back before electricity in the modern sense was discovered. It is always wise to check the history of terms.

Comment: @user159691: My point was the futility of the argument, not the validity of it. Etymology is not always logically efficient (as per the OP's assertion); which is my point (and yours, I think).

Comment: But the full OED ***does*** include a dedicated entry for [**farcic**](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/68160?redirectedFrom=farcic#eid) - defined as ***Obsolete, rare.** Equivalent to adjectival **farcical***.

Comment: numerical, orientate, utilization, ...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[Farcical](https://www.etymonline.com/word/farcical) is from early 18th century, from farce +  suffix -ical.

Suffix ***[-ical](https://www.etymonline.com/word/-ical)***  has an earlier origin than  -ic, with which it is usually Interchangeable. Its usage probably became common because  the forms in -ic often took on a noun sense (for example physic).

> compound adjectival word-forming element, usually interchangeable with -ic but sometimes with specialized sense (such as historic/historical, politic/political)....... Forms in -ical tend to be attested earlier in English than their twins in -ic.

(Etymonline)

Comment: Etymology online is a general reference. This shouldn't be an answer.

Comment: Farsic and farcical are not like historic and historical. Farsic is obsolete.

Answer (score 3):

Farcical etymologies are few and far between in the *OED*, but its etymology of *farcical* fits.

> Etymology: formed as **farcic** *adj. + **-al** suffix*.

This seems to be absurd, because **farcical** is first attested in **1715**, whereas **farcic** has only one attestation from **1763**.

The *OED* does offer this description of the *-ical* suffix:.

> Many adjectives have a form both in *-ic* and *-ical*, and in such cases that in *-ical* is usually the earlier and that more used. **Often also the form in *-ic* is restricted to the sense ‘of’ or ‘of the nature of’ the subject in question, while that in *-ical* has wider or more transferred senses, including that of ‘practically connected’ or ‘dealing with’ the subject.**

The bold emphasis is mine, because I think this note might be relevant to "farcical."  Consider the difference between "comic" and "comical" as an analogy.  Something that is "comical" is not necessarily directly related to the art of "comedy."

> The comical atmosphere in the room had us all laughing.

Here, "comical" expresses less attachment to "comedy" than would "comic."

Similarly, something that is "farcical" is probably not directly related to the literal meaning of *farce*:

> A dramatic work (usually short) which has for its sole object to excite laughter